# Unable to deploy eclipse project on glassfish server

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I'm trying to develop my app on glassfish, I use eclipse luna, but I get the following error:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of
>   type: br.com.hrtech.atendimento.listener.ContadorSessao, because it
>   does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener,
>   ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener,
>   ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or
>   HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces. Please see server.log for
>   more details.

I tought that was something about `web.xml` and I have this code but I can't undderstand what is wrong:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Has someone ever seen this ????

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clearly describing the problem:

> Unable to add listener of type:
>   br.com.hrtech.atendimento.listener.ContadorSessao, because it does not
>   implement any of the required ServletContextListener,
>   ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener,
>   ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or
>   HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces.

The message says you have registered a class named `br.com.hrtech.atendimento.listener.ContadorSessao` as a listener (probably in `web.xml`), which doesn't implement any of the required interfaces.

You have to implement one of these interfaces in your class if you want to register it as a listener.

So either you can do something like this:

```
public class ContadorSessao implements ServletContextListener {

   // implement all required methods

}
```

or, if this really shouldn't be a listener, there seems to be an entry in your `web.xml` looking like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>br.com.hrtech.atendimento.listener.ContadorSessao</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Remove this entry and it should work.

If the problem doesn't get fixed by one of these solutions, make sure that you `Clean & Build` your project before redeploying it with the new settings.

By the way, the part of the your `web.xml` you posted, indicates that you are using obsolete and deprecated technologies (namely JSP) which doesn't make any sense in 2014 if you develop a new web app which should run on Glassfish (I guess at least version 3). For a standard JSF 2.x web application you shouldn't need something like `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`.

You should consider switching to a more recent "software stack" (JSF 2, EJB 3.1, JPA 2).

Comment: if i delete the listener it doesn´t work too, it says cannot deploy...i forgot to say that the project comes from svn repository.

Comment: I guess you get a different error after removing the listener. Maybe you can update your question with this or ask a new question.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. And the class referred to in web.xml DOES implement  HttpSessionListener